# IBM i/AS400 System health email

Tags: ibm-midrange, websphere

I would like to set up a daily summary email on our IBM I/AS 400 system health like CPU usage and ASP usage % and eventually setup alerts if the storage usage or the CPU usage increases to a certain % - How to achieve this ? currently I am doing an WRKSYSSTS manually and keeping an eye on the storage and would like some solution that automates this process.

Comment: you might start by enabling QSYSMSG (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rbam6/qsysm.htm ) and setting up a program to send e-mails when messages arrive in it.

Answer (score 1):

select * from QSYS2.SYSTEM_STATUS_INFO will give you a lot of that info.  I use it for sending alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SystemStatus](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/doc/com/ibm/as400/access/SystemStatus.html) class to get this done.
I use below program to get the AS400 system status data.

```
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;
import com.ibm.as400.access.SystemStatus;

public class SystemStat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "server_host_name";
        String user = "server_user_name";
        String pass = "server_password";

        AS400 as400 = null;

        try {
            // Create an AS400 object  
            as400 = new AS400(server, user, pass);

            SystemStatus systemStatus = new SystemStatus(as400);

            System.out.println("Current Processing Capacity :" + systemStatus.getCurrentProcessingCapacity());
            System.out.println("ASPUsed:" + systemStatus.getPercentSystemASPUsed());
            System.out.println("Temp Addresses Used:" + systemStatus.getPercentTemporaryAddresses());


        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```