# JT400 - Work with Media Information (WRKMEDIBRM)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

Does anyone know how to work with AS400 media ( Tapes ) in JT400 Java.
I need to get the tape details via a Java program. ( WRKMEDIBRM )

Thanks
Buddhika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Backup, Recovery, and Media Services (BRMS) is a separately install-able and chargeable product.

That being said, BRMS does have it own set of [APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzai8/rzai8_api.htm)

However, JT400 doesn't include any specific functionality for interacting with the BRMS product.

A quick glance through the BRMS APIs seems to show that they all use a (OPM) *PGM interface.  So JT400's [ProgramCall class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahh/pgmc.htm) would be sufficient to call them.

**EDIT**
JT400 also has a [CommandCall class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahh/cmdc.htm) , but it's only useful for commands that don't invoke a program with a interactive UI.  So for example, you couldn't call `WRKSYSSTS` as mentioned in your comment.

For interacting with BRMS, the best option would be using it's APIs and teh ProgramCall class.

Comment: I'm wondering whether I can get a reply to a command call using same class. For an example if I execute WRKSYSSTS can I get the ASP percentage and such values displayed in the command result.

Comment: There's a difference between programs *PGM and commands *CMD.  See edit...

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533906/ibm-i-as400-system-health-email/60535938#60535938 for how to get most info that WRKSYSSTS has.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Thanks for the answer, I have provided a java program where you could extract System Status data without connecting to the DB by using JT400 SystemStatus class.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533906/ibm-i-as400-system-health-email/60535938#60535938

What I am looking here is a way to get the details which gets in to the Access Client screen after we do a program call.